# Calculate time period overlap and use aggregation to find out remaining time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `timings` table with the following definition:

```
   Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 start_time | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
 end_time   | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
 type       | integer                     |           | not null |
```

It has data such as this:

```
     start_time      |      end_time       | type
---------------------+---------------------+------
 2020-11-10 23:50:00 | 2020-11-10 23:50:17 |    1
 2020-11-11 23:50:17 | 2020-11-11 23:50:34 |    1
 2020-11-10 23:50:08 | 2020-11-10 23:50:15 |    2
 2020-11-15 23:50:08 | 2020-11-16 23:50:08 |    2
```

**Calculation**

For each *date* where the `type = 1`, I would like to work out the time difference in seconds between the `start_time` and `end_time`. So for *row 1* the time difference is *17 seconds*.

And then, I want to subtract/take away any time overlap for the same date where `type = 2`. For example *row 3* has a difference of 7 seconds, and the `start_time` and `end_time` all fall into the `start_time` and `end_time` for *row 1* (they are the same date). So we take away `7` from `17` and we're left with `10`.

If a row with `type = 2` has a date that doesn't match any dates where `type = 1` then that row can be ignored (for example, row 4 is totally ignored).

I'd like this to happen for all dates and then sum up the total across all dates. In this case, I'll have a total of **27** because we just have *row 2*'s time difference (17) to add, so `10 + 17` gives us `27`.

**Desired Output**

```
   type_one_seconds   
----------------------
 27
```

I haven't worked with time-period calculations in SQL before, I'm not really sure where to start.

**Assumptions**

I had a comment/question that disappeared. It asked what happens when I have two rows with the same date where `type = 1`. I'll have to check my data and get back to you to see if this ever happens. For now, let's assume each `type = 1` will have a unique date. So we just sum up their time difference. But I'll check this and make sure.

I have created a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gLw8xZPkf1btdYmFSiUD9o/0).

Comment: Excellent question. Upvote for the detail information and fiddle link. I have just one question. If any rows with type 2 partially overlap with rows with type 1 will that partially overlapped time being deducted?

Comment: Thanks, @KaziMohammadAliNur and yep, any partially overlapped time will be deducted.

Comment: Ok. Then please let me revise my answer.

Comment: What if start_time and end_time of a row with type=2 do not fall fully but only partially into the start_time and end_time for a row with type=1?

Comment: @forpas then only the bit of time that falls within is to be calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try splitting your conditions into `CASE`s:

```
SELECT sum(sec) FROM (
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN type = 1 THEN
      EXTRACT(SECOND FROM end_time-start_time)
    WHEN type = 2 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM timings 
                                  WHERE type = 1 AND
                                    (start_time::date = t.start_time::date OR
                                     end_time::date = t.end_time::date)) THEN 0
    WHEN type = 2 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM timings
                              WHERE start_time < t.start_time AND 
                                    end_time > t.end_time AND
                                    type = 1) THEN        
      EXTRACT(SECOND FROM end_time-start_time) * -1    
  END AS sec
FROM timings t) j;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0d336bc691bc5bfb17d0a2af95a2462b)

Answer (score 1):

If there are partial partial overlapped between time ranges:

Here `tsrange()` is used to find out overlapping times between two time ranges.

```
 -- create the table
 create table timings (
   start_time timestamp not null,
   end_time timestamp not null,
   type integer not null
 );
 
 
 -- insert data into the table
 insert into timings (start_time, end_time, type) values
    ('2020-11-10 23:50:00', '2020-11-10 23:50:17' ,1),
    ('2020-11-11 23:50:17', '2020-11-11 23:50:34' ,1),
    ('2020-11-10 23:50:08', '2020-11-10 23:50:15' ,2),
    ('2020-11-10 23:50:15', '2020-11-10 23:50:25' ,2),
    ('2020-11-15 23:50:08', '2020-11-16 23:50:08' ,2);
```

Query:

```
 WITH TIMEONE AS
     (
         select *, coalesce( EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (t1.end_time - t1.start_time)),0) timeone 
         from timings  t1 
         where type=1
     ),
 
 timeonetwo as 
 (
     select *,
         (select sum( coalesce( EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (upper(diff) - lower(diff))),0) ) from
         (select tsrange(t2.start_time, t2.end_time, '[]') * tsrange(t1.start_time, t1.end_time, '[]')diff
     from timings t2 where type=2)t)timetwosum
 from timeone t1
 )
 select sum(timeone-timetwosum)type_one_seconds  from timeonetwo
```

Output:

| type_one_seconds |
| --- |
| 25 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7140cc0d1c953b5f5735028c1fa17253)*

If there is no partial overlapped:

```
 -- create the table
 create table timings (
   start_time timestamp not null,
   end_time timestamp not null,
   type integer not null
 );
 
 
 -- insert data into the table
 insert into timings (start_time, end_time, type) values
    ('2020-11-10 23:50:00', '2020-11-10 23:50:17' ,1),
    ('2020-11-11 23:50:17', '2020-11-11 23:50:34' ,1),
    ('2020-11-10 23:50:08', '2020-11-10 23:50:15' ,2),
    ('2020-11-15 23:50:08', '2020-11-16 23:50:08' ,2);
```

Query:

```
 select sum(timeone-timetwosum)type_one_seconds  
 from
 (
     select coalesce( EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (t1.end_time - t1.start_time)),0) timeone ,
     coalesce((select  sum(coalesce( EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (t2.end_time - t2.start_time)),0) )
     from timings t2 where t2.type=2 
     and t2.start_time =t1.start_time and t2.end_time<=t1.end_time),0) timetwosum
 
     from timings  t1 
     where type=1
 )t
```

Output:

| type_one_seconds |
| --- |
| 27 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4dd80c028c1894c71a18f810c59bb366)*

Comment: After the update, I get `34` as the output, but I think it should remain `27`, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no time overlap between rows within a `type`, I would use the `tsrange` datatype to take advantage of its intersect `*` and overlap `&&` operators:

```
with ranges as (
  select type, tsrange(start_time, end_time) as rng
    from timings
), find_neg as (
  select n.type, p.rng * n.rng as rng
    from ranges p
         join ranges n
           on n.type = 2
          and p.type = 1
          and n.rng && p.rng
  union all
  select type, rng
    from ranges
   where type = 1
)
select sum(extract(epoch from upper(rng) - lower(rng))) filter (where type = 1)
       - sum(extract(epoch from upper(rng) - lower(rng))) filter (where type = 2)
  from find_neg;
```

If there are overlaps within a `type`, then I would consolidate them first using a gaps-and-islands strategy.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3481b35f19335424baecd094c0762ed0)

Answer (score 1):

Use a self join of the table.
Each row with `type = 1` will be joined with a `LEFT` join to its counterpart with `type = 2` and with a `CASE` expression you can calculate the differences of `end_time` and  `start_time` for each type and subtract.
The functions `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` will be used to narrow the interval of the row with `type = 2` inside the time limits of the corresponding row with `type = 1`.
Finally aggregate with `SUM()`:

```
SELECT SUM(
            EXTRACT(SECOND FROM t1.end_time - t1.start_time) -
            CASE  
              WHEN t2.type IS NULL THEN 0 
              ELSE EXTRACT(SECOND FROM LEAST(t1.end_time, t2.end_time) - GREATEST(t1.start_time, t2.start_time)) 
            END  
          ) type_one_seconds
FROM timings t1 LEFT JOIN timings t2
ON t2.start_time::date = t1.start_time::date AND t2.type = 2 
WHERE t1.type = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d6b69c41c0df40479e7d24056a604756).